# Best practice with two Java related clases like Recipe and Ingredient

Tags: java, class

I have two clases Recipe and Ingredient (with: ingredientName, quantity, unit) and two ways to connect those two clases.

1. A Recipe object contains a list of Ingredient objects
   (List or ArrayList).
2. A Ingredient object contains the id of the related Recipe object.

Which one is the best practice for performance considering the fact that I will need in the app to find out which Recipe objects contains a particular Ingredient.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you're going to post a homework question, at least tell us what you think the correct answer is and why. Also, do you think that the two structures are mutually exclusive?

Comment: I think the best way is the first one because is logic, but I think that the second one make more simple to query by Ingredients, for a Java begginer like me. And I don't know the performance implications.

Comment: Interesting question, but you need to give more detail about your solution so far, and what exactly an `Ingredient` object represents. For example, if one recipe requires 20ml of "Olive Oil", but a second recipe requires 10ml of "Olive Oil", does the `Ingredient` object represent just "Olive Oil", or does it also represent the amount too?

Comment: In first case in Ingredient class I will have the ingredientName, the quantity and the unit type.

Comment: With that structure, won't the "20ml of olive oil" `Ingredient` only find recipes which use exactly that amount of olive oil? Are you aiming to find all recipes which use olive oil, in any amount, or is this specific exact-quantity-match sufficient?

Comment: I don't need exact-quantity-match in the query, but i need the amount to be and int to calculate the calories and to calculate the quantities according to the number of servings.

Comment: To find matching recipes by type rather than by specific quantity, I think you'll need to split your ingredient class into two: an `Ingredient` class which just holds the ingredient name, and overrides the `equals` method and the `hashCode` method to consider just this name; and an `IngredientQuantity` class which refers to an `IngredientType` but also contains fields for the amount unit (use an enum with members such as MILLIMETERS, GRAMS, PIECES, etc) and the numeric amount. That way you can build a `Map<IngredientType, Set<Recipe>>` which maps from ingredient type to recipes.

Comment: Thanks @Bobulous! And how do I add the quantities of ingredients to a `Recipe` object?

Comment: I've posted an answer to show how the `IngredientQuantity` class would look, and to give some description about how this would fit in between `Recipe` and `Ingredient`. But I suspect this question is probably too broad to be solved with a single answer. Have a go at writing the code for your application, and ask a question on Stack Overflow when you have very specific problem which is puzzling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow a `Recipe` to refer to an ingredient type separately to the quantity of that ingredient, I'd suggest creating an `Ingredient` class and an `IngredientQuantity` class.

The `Ingredient` class represents a type of ingredient, with no knowledge of quantity. As a simple starting point, the `Ingredient` class might contain just a `String` which holds the ingredient name, but you could add other fields to represent other useful data about this ingredient type. We'll need to use this `Ingredient` class as a key in a `Map` later, so make sure you override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods within your `Ingredient` class, otherwise it won't work as a key.

The `IngredientQuantity` class represents a particular ingredient in a particular quantity, and its outline might look like this:

```
public final class IngredientQuantity {

    public static enum QuantityUnit {
        // Add other unit types here.
        PIECE, MILLILITRE, GRAMME
    }

    private final Ingredient ingredient;
    private final QuantityUnit unit;
    private final double quantity;

    public IngredientQuantity(Ingredient ingredient, QuantityUnit unit,
            double quantity) {
        this.ingredient = Objects.requireNonNull(ingredient);
        this.unit = Objects.requireNonNull(unit);
        this.quantity = quantity;
        if (quantity < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quantity cannot be negative.");
        }
    }   
}
```

(This has been simplified, so you'll have to add getter methods, and other required functionality.)

Now your `Recipe` class can contain a `Collection<IngredientQuantity>` which describes the quantity of each ingredient required for the recipe. If you need to be paranoid about allowing each ingredient type only once then you could use a `Map<Ingredient, IngredientQuantity>` to detect duplicates. But if you're in control of building the recipes objects then you should be able to avoid duplicates anyway.

Either way, you now have a way to get from a `Recipe` to the collection of `Ingredient` objects which are required.

To get from `Ingredient` to `Recipe` you need to build up a `Map<Ingredient, Set<Recipe>>` which maps from each `Ingredient` object to all of the `Recipe` objects which require that ingredient type. You would need to populate this as you read the recipes into your application, iterating through the ingredients of each recipe and then adding that `Recipe` to the map under the `Ingredient` key within the map.

If your application has a large number of recipes, such that it cannot read in all of the recipes at the start of the application, then you'd have to instead have the mapping data stored with the recipe data, such as in the database or data file structure itself. But that's a very different question.